# How to get a prop object to pass from one React component to the other in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass a custom object from one React component to the others, and can't figure out what TypeScript needs to have defined.

Here are the two component files:

**FlashcardList.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Flashcard from './Flashcard';

interface FlashcardListProps {
    flashcards: any[]
}

const FlashcardList = ({ flashcards }: FlashcardListProps) => (
    <div className="content">
        {flashcards.map(flashcard => <Flashcard flashcard={flashcard} key={flashcard.id} />)}
    </div>
);

export default FlashcardList;
```

LINE: `{flashcards.map(flashcard => <Flashcard flashcard={flashcard} key={flashcard.id} />)}`
**ERROR: Type '{ flashcard: any; key: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
Property 'flashcard' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'**

**Flashcard.tsx:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
const greyBox = require('../images/greybox.png');

interface Flashcard {
    category: String,
    front: String,
    back: String
}
interface FlashcardState {
    flashcard: Flashcard
}

class Flashcard extends Component<{}, FlashcardState> {

    constructor(props: FlashcardState) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            flashcard: Flashcard
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="flashcard">
                <div className="front">{this.state.flashcard.category.toUpperCase()}: {this.state.flashcard.front}</div>
                <div className="back">{this.state.flashcard.back}</div>
                <div className="text-success">test of bootstrap</div>
                <img src={greyBox} alt="grey box" className="img-fluid" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Flashcard;
```

LINE: `flashcard: Flashcard`
**ERROR: Type 'typeof Flashcard' is missing the following properties from type 'Flashcard': category, front, back, render, and 6 more.ts(2740)
Flashcard.tsx(19, 15): Did you mean to use 'new' with this expression?**

What do I need to change so that TypeScript has what it needs in terms of types/interfaces as the object `flashcard` is passed from one component to the other via props?

Comment: Two issues: 1. you've defined flashcard as part of the *state* of `Flashcard`, but are actually passing it as a *prop* (where it isn't defined); and 2. `this.state = { flashcard: Flashcard }` is an object literal, there's no type information there; you're trying to use an *interface* (which doesn't exist in the emitted JavaScript) as a *value*.

Comment: Also you've shadowed your interface with the class, they have the same name. In this case it seems like you don't need state at all - you can use a function component for both (and even in function components there's `useState` now).

Answer (score 0):

I admit the above question was a bit clueless, but @jonrsharpe above helped point the way for me to fix all the problems and get it to work, thanks.

For anyone else struggling with TypeScript syntax in React components, here are the two above files changed so that they now work. Note above all in **FlashcardList.tsx** the change from sending the whole object as a prop (`flashcard={flashcard}`) to sending the deconstructed parameters of the object using the *spread operator* (`{...flashcard}`) which are then received in **Flashcard.tsx** as props of that component, i.e. the whole component being of type `IFlashcard` and so simply receives the deconstructed parameters individually as props.

**FlashcardList.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Flashcard from './Flashcard';

interface IFlashcard {
    id: number,
    category: string,
    front: string,
    back: string,
    key: number
}

interface IFlashcardListProps {
    flashcards: IFlashcard[]
}

const FlashcardList = ({ flashcards }: IFlashcardListProps) => (
    <div className="content">
        {flashcards.map(flashcard => <Flashcard {...flashcard} key={flashcard.id} />)}
    </div>
);

export default FlashcardList;
```

**Flashcard.tsx:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
const greyBox = require('../images/greybox.png');

interface IFlashcard {
    category: string,
    front: string,
    back: string
}

class Flashcard extends Component<IFlashcard> {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="flashcard">
                <div className="front">{this.props.category.toUpperCase()}: {this.props.front}</div>
                <div className="back">{this.props.back}</div>
                <div className="text-success">test of bootstrap</div>
                <img src={greyBox} alt="grey box" className="img-fluid" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Flashcard;
```